# Issue loading MY profile picture in AS3

Tags: facebook, flash, actionscript-3, profile, image

I'm having issues loading MY profile picture from a Flash App ON Facebook. It works fine locally, but when I upload to Facebook it loads this profile picture for ME ONLY (not my friends): http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/

Here's what I'm doing:

1. Get the Facebook ID of my friends and me
2. Create a URL string: graph.facebook.com/[FACEBOOK ID]/picture?type=large for each of my friends and me.
3. Throw the URLs into loaders and load!
4. Facebook returns the actual address to each image: ie: http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/370825_524761447_653077984_n.jpg
5. Throw the RETURNED address into another loader and then load the final, actual image.

Once this is done, the images are all loaded for all my friends, but for some reason, MY profile image always loads the generic one up at the beginning of the post (the profile.ak.fbcdn.net address without anything following...). It's this way for ANY user that's logged in. I've tested it on several profiles and had my friends test the app as well, they ALL get that generic picture as "their" picture ...

On a side note: The code worked fine before Christmas break in 2011 ... and when we came back to school in 2012 it didn't work any more, and we didn't change any of our code. I wonder if this is a Facebook API bug and not something we did.

Comment: Are you listening for any IOError or SecurityError events when trying to load the pictures of your friends. This looks to me like a security issue, which is bypassed into the debugging version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (put it somewhere when your app launches):

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://graph.facebook.com/crossdomain.xml");
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml");
Security.loadPolicyFile("https://graph.facebook.com/crossdomain.xml");
Security.loadPolicyFile("https://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml");
Security.allowDomain("*");
Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
```

It could also have something to do with facebook changing security stuff. Every app needs to be run on a certified https server these days...

Comment: That worked perfectly! I just put that in the constructor of my Flash client! Thanks a ton, I've wasted MANY hours looking for this bug ....